# QT button click to change plaintextedit

Tags: c++, qt, connect, textedit, slot

I'm totally new to QT. I've written a little form with 4 radio buttons, click button and plain text edit field (in QT Creator). My goal is to press push button and get a text change in the plaintextedit ("Some text here"). Unfortunately I can't find the right formula for connecting the button and the text field, so I get an error, I can't figure out yet. Here's the code (I omit the GUI XML part):

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QRadioButton radioButton,radioButton_2,radioButton_3,radioButton_4;
    QPushButton pushButton;
    QPlainTextEdit plainTextEdit;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
//#include <QPushButton>
//#include <QPlainTextEdit>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),plainTextEdit,SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    plainTextEdit.setPlainText("Some text here");
}
```

Here's the error output:

```
/home/user/workspace/ButtonRadio/mainwindow.cpp:-1: In constructor 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
/home/user/workspace/ButtonRadio/mainwindow.cpp:11: error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QPushButton&, const char*, QPlainTextEdit&, const char*)'
/home/user/workspace/ButtonRadio/mainwindow.cpp:11: candidates are:
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:204: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const QObject*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType)
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:204: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QPushButton' to 'const QObject*'
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:217: static bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, const QObject*, const QMetaMethod&, Qt::ConnectionType)
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:217: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QPushButton' to 'const QObject*'
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:337: bool QObject::connect(const QObject*, const char*, const char*, Qt::ConnectionType) const
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:337: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'QPushButton' to 'const QObject*'
```

If I write just

```
QObject::connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
```

then the error output slightly changes, but the essence is still the same. How can I solve this problem?

--EDIT--15.11.14--

mainwindow.h:
    ...

```
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QRadioButton *radioButton,*radioButton_2,*radioButton_3,*radioButton_4;
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    pushButton(new QPushButton(this)),
    plainTextEdit(new QPlainTextEdit(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
    //plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
    QObject::connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),plainTextEdit,SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    plainTextEdit->setPlainText("Some text here");
}
```

As a result, I get SIGSEGV with the following output:

```
amember "1on_pushButton_clicked()" char *
asender @0x2 QObject
asignal "2clicked()" char *
atype Qt::AutoConnection(0) Qt::ConnectionType
this @0x7fffffffe640 QObject
```

It also points to the following lines in qobject.h:

```
339 { return connect(asender, asignal, this, amember, atype); }
349 T qFindChild(const QObject *o, const QString &name = QString());
350 QList<T> qFindChildren(const QObject *oobj, const QString &name = QString());
351 QList<T> qFindChildren(const QObject *o, const QRegExp &re);
```

Comment: QRadioButton *radioButton,*radioButton_2,*radioButton_3,*radioButton_4;
    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit; ,  then allocate memory with new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because `connect` use pointers. You should use pointers:

```
QRadioButton *radioButton,*radioButton_2,*radioButton_3,*radioButton_4;
QPushButton *pushButton;
QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit;
```

When you use pointer every `.` replace with `->`. Compiler tells you about mistake with next error:

```
...(maybe you meant to use '->' ?) radioButton_2.show();
```

And connect should be:

```
connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
```

or

```
connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
```

On future: you can also write this:

```
QObject obj1;
QObject obj2;
connect(&obj1,SIGNAL(someSigna()),&obj2,SLOT(slot()));
```

As you can see, you need `&`

You need to write `QObject::connect` in not `QObject` subclasses (for example in `main.cpp`) In your `MainWindow` you can write just `connect`

Also when you use pointers you should allocate memory with `new`. For example:

```
pushButton = new QPushButton(this);//in constructor
//and so on
```

where `this` shows us that `this` (our `MainWindow`) is parent, so `pushButton` will appear in `MainWindow`, not in the separate window.

I think I mentioned all big mistakes in this code.

`on_pushButton_clicked()` is slot of mainwindow, not a plaintexteditTry next:

```
pushButton = new QPushButton(this);
plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
connect(pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
```

Comment: `*radioButton_2`, `*radioButton_3`, `*radioButton_4`.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for this long delay with my comment.
I've done what you've said - changed variables to pointers (you were so right!), created an allocation for pushButton, changed "." to "->" in the on_pushButton_clicked(), but I get SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault in the end. Can't figure out how to post code here in this reply window...

Comment: @user1274925 Did you allocate memory for plaintext too? If no, then try to do it. If it will not help, then press edit oj your answer, and add your current code.

Comment: I did it too, but with the same result - SIGSEGV. As the debugger points out, the problem is with pushButton.

Comment: @user1274925 edit your question and post full code. I can't suggest something if I "blind".

Comment: Thanks, it's done. I just had no idea I could do it by editing the main post instead of posting it here in comments.

Comment: Great, now it does work, thank you! The only problem is that now there appears a superfluous text field where the output goes to, not the one I created, but there must be some bug in the GUI file, gonna look at it now.

Comment: Yes, I've done it! THanks for teaching me good SO manners as well ;)